# Call C++ function providing only some of default parameters

Tags: c++

### Question

Let's say I have a function:

```cpp
int foo(int a, int b, int c = 5, int d = 10){
    return a + b + c + d;
}
```

How can I call it providing `a`, `b` and `d` but not `c`?

### Concrete example

I want to use `cv::erode` documented [here](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d4/d86/group__imgproc__filter.html#gaeb1e0c1033e3f6b891a25d0511362aeb)

```cpp
void cv::erode  (   InputArray  src,
OutputArray     dst,
InputArray  kernel,
Point   anchor = Point(-1,-1),
int     iterations = 1,
int     borderType = BORDER_CONSTANT,
const Scalar &  borderValue = morphologyDefaultBorderValue() 
)
```

and provide (except of required arguments) only `iterations`, but use default value for `anchor`. Apparently, pythonic approach does not work `cv::erode(img, out, kernel, iterations=radius);` :(

Comment: Although I'll save you the click. The answer is, unfortunately: you can't.

Comment: Call it as if there is no argument d, like foo(a,b,c);

Comment: Create three overloads of your function `foo`: One taking only `a` and `b` as arguments, it calls `foo(a, b, 5, 10)`; One taking `a`, `b` and `d` as arguments, it calls `foo(a, b, 5, d)`; And the last taking all four arguments without default values.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Overloads won't work here because the two shorter overloads would both have signature `int foo(int, int, int)` and would be indistinguishable.

Comment: Hmm, that seems a bizarre limitation of the language... Thanks for help.

Comment: default arguments are rather limited. Consider that its a whole different story in languages that have named parameters, which C++ doesnt. As a caller, how would you tell  what parameters are explicitly given and for which the defaults should be used in eg:  `foo(1,2,3)`. There needs to be a rule and that is: parameters may only be ommited starting from right

Comment: @SilvioMayolo Three overloads: One taking *two* arguments; One taking *three* arguments; And the last taking *four* arguments. And none of them with default argument values.